# Set text alignment listboxitem Delphi XE5 FM during runtime not working

Tags: delphi, alignment, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, listboxitem

I want to change the alignment of a litboxitem that is creatd at runtim and added to a simple listbox.

- If you add a listview item in the design window before runtime, you can easily adjust the alignment by:

```
listboxitem1.VertTextAlign := TTextAlign.taTrailing;
listboxitem1.TextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter;
```

- However when the object is created during runtime it simply does not work that way. While the height for instance does:

```
listboxitem2 := Tlistboxitem.Create(self);
listboxitem2.Text := 'itemtext';
listboxitem2.Height := 100;
listboxitem2.VertTextAlign := TTextAlign.taTrailing;
listboxitem2.TextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter;
listboxitem2.Name := 'itemname';
listbox1.AddObject(listboxitem2);
```

What is wrong about this code?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what it looks like when you create it at designtime, vs runtime, to illustrate the difference? (Saves time-short people writing and running the code.) If your account doesn't have permission yet to attach an image, upload it to imgur and edit your post to include a link, and someone will edit it in for you.)

Comment: Of course! I'll add some screenshots next time. (Mike already solved the issue) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings such as this are normally pulled from the style. The StyledSettings property tells FM which properties should be pulled from the style, others will be set from properties. If you edit a property at design time the editor will adjust the StyledSettings property for you. At run time you need to do that manually.

Try adding:

```
listboxitem2.StyledSettings := listboxitem2.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.ssOther];
```